# How to exclude a specific .class file in an aar package using Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I want to exclude a specific .class file in an aar dependency and replace it using my own .java file to fix a bug. As known it can be done to exclude dependencies by  "`exclude group:`" in Gradle. Is there any similar way to exclude a particular .class file from a dependency as well? Thanks for any help!